# Saving php code into a file without interpreting it

Tags: php, save, file-put-contents

How can i save php script/code into a file using PHP without interpreting the PHP script before saving it.

```
$_POST['posted_code'] = "<html> some cool text <?php print 'Hi, i cant be saved because am being interpreted'; ?> <img> <script></script> <?php include('file'); ?></html>";
```

I tried

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
file_put_contents('new_file.php',$_POST['posted_code']);
```

**But i landed on 403 forbidden**, and without php script it's saving.

How can i solve this to have the code saved in an later interpreted way

Answer (score 0):

Can you please surround your posted_code in single quotes like 'posted_code'.

Try below code which will save your php script/code into a file without interpreting the PHP script

```
$_POST['posted_code'] = "<html> some cool text <?php print 'Hi, i cant be saved because am being interpreted'; ?> <img> <script></script> <?php include('file'); ?></html>";
```

Also make changes here

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
file_put_contents('new_file.php',$_POST['posted_code']);
```

Comment: You have only quoted the $_POST index posted_code, why should it work?

Comment: Becoz if you have to assign string in $_POST in posted_code then the key should be surrounded with the ''/"" quotes then only it will save it into the $_POST. Have you tried my code yet?